# How can I create complex edge profiles on columns?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, geometry

I'm a complete beginner to Blender and I'm trying to create an accurate model of the Tuscan Order, based on William Chambers' "Treatise on Civil Architecture" from 1759.

So far I've made a rough outline of it using only cylinders and cubes of various dimensions. I haven't figured out how to properly curve/round their sides however.

This is what it looks like at the moment:

[image]

There are a couple of different types of curvings I'll need to do, as can be seen below:

[image]

1. Make the sides of the cylinder completely rounded, and have the flat upper face begin where the next part of the column stands (i.e. make it in the shape of a half-circle).
2. Make the shaft of the column slightly taper outwards where it ends.
3. Make the sides of the cylinder rounded, but only from one direction. (i.e. make it in the shape of a quarter-circle)
4. Make a Cyma Reversa (inverted s-shape)
5. Make a Cyma Recta (s-shape)

I'd be grateful for any help I can get, whether it's for all, or just one of these curvings!

Answer (score 9):

For the circular base, you can use the *Screw modifier*.
That way you can easily change the shape and number of sides.

1. Create a profile from vertices or using a Bezier curve
2. Add a Screw modifier
3. Done

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One more quick question though - why does my screw modifier keep spinning the profile across the wrong axis? I've toggled Z, but it ends up looking like this: https://ibb.co/CJBkKYw

Comment: Hello :). Perhaps your object has un-applied rotation. Go *Object > Apply > Rotation*, that should help.

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish most of what you want using a bevel. Select an edge between two other edges that you want a "round transtion" between and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>B</kbd>. You can control the number of subdivisions by scrolling the <kbd>Mousewheel</kbd> and control the size of the bevel by moving the mouse.

[image: BevelEdge]

There is even the option to set a custom profile, giving you more control over the shape of the curve.

[image: BevelCurve]

The last shape (bottom in your image) can be accomplished selecting both the top and bottom edges of a cylinder, and beveling them together.

[image: BevelDouble]