# Rotate an SVG file with a correct front view around it's own top axis, so it becomes a cylinder

Tags: modeling, svg

I can imagine this would be one of the simplest techniques there is in Blender, but I am a complete beginner to modeling.
What I am trying to do is as follows: I made a shape in Adobe Illustrator, saved this as an SVG. Now the image is a front view of the model I am trying to create. All I want blender to do, is make a cylinder of the top (flat) view (for reference, the model I am trying to create is a dart barrel - which is always a cylinder with some cut-outs).

So image 1 is the front view. Image 2 is the current top view. Image 3 is what I want image 2 to look like. Simple enough I guess, but as said: complete beginner :)

[image: Example image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78961. You should probably ditch half of your dart section,when revolved 360 degrees it would overlap itself

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Yes, I understand that if you were to repeat-rotate it 360 degrees it'd overlap itself for 180 degrees. But I don't need to rotate it for 360 degrees, I just need a working method of making the flat image a cylinder. How this would work and what this method would entail, I have no idea. Hence the question :)

Comment: Hello Thomas :). The solution linked by @Duarte is showing the easiest way to do that in Blender. Just use the screw modifier. Here's [another answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/187015/78972) using the same approach.

Comment: @JachymMichal Ooh I am sorry, I didn't see it was linked! My bad, thank you very much!!!

Comment: No problem :). If you get stuck anywhere, feel free to ask a new question :).