# How do I round off an extrusion edge?

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to create a part of a column from a church and I'm getting to the section where it is a torus shape, which then goes back to a straight column, here is where I got to with the part highlighted.

[image]

Comment: Related: [How can I create complex edge profiles on columns?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/187012/78972)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extrude up, create a loopcut with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, select the face ring:

[image]

Extrude and scale except on Z (<kbd>E</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>):

[image]

Now select the top and bottom edge loop and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel (use the middle mouse to choose the number of segments, also tweak the values in the *Operator* box):

[image]

Comment: Cool thank you, that's perfect! How do I extrude the egdes like you you did? When I select all of the faces on my object, the extrusion just goes in one direction.

Comment: I've edited, I hope it helps

Comment: Amazing, thank you :)